# getExternalFilesDirs() doesn't return the card, inserted while my app was running

Tags: android

If the SD card was inserted at the moment of my app start, I see it in `getExternalFilesDirs()` result.

But if I insert the card while my app is running (on background), `getExternalFilesDirs()` continues return the list without it. Until I restart an app.

Any ideas on how to make it read the effective state on the fly?

Comment: Idea: watch intents https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html?hl=fr#ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED

Comment: Watching the broadcast might tell you of media changes, but you don't have an obvious way to force `getExternalFilesDirs()` to start returning the proper values. It's possible that starting some other `Context` (e.g., running a service) will cause `getExternalFilesDirs()` on that `Context` to return proper values.